# How to "Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Tags: php-7.1, magento-2.3

I am getting a warning:

```
{"0":"Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in \/app\/code\/Mageplaza\/LayeredNavigation\/Helper\/Data.php on line 68"
```

line 68 looks like

```
foreach ($filterParams as $key=>$param){
            $filterParams[$key] = htmlspecialchars($param);
}
```

Please help. PHP version is 7.1

Comment: are you sure $param is a string? add a var_dump($param) at the beginning of the foreach loop

Comment: `$filterParams` is probably a more complex construct than you thought. The error message says it all, apparently `$param` can be an array too, and not just a string.